# Is every language with a single letter alphabet is decidable?

Tags: regular-language

I'm studying for an exam in theoretical informatics. I have a question for which I can't find an answer. 
Is every language with the following alphabet decidable:

`∑ ={1}`

I need to explain why it is or isn't.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the case that every language of the alphabet is decidable. This is because of the following argument which is based on the fact that not every language over $\{ 0, 1 \}$ is decidable.

Assume for a contradiction that every language over $\{ 1\}$ is decidable i.e. for every language over $\{ 1\}$ there is a TM $M$ which stops on any input and accepts exactly the specified language. Let $L$ be any language over $\{0, 1\}$. Define the function $f: \{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow \{ 1\}^*, f(w) = Dec(1w)$. $f$ is a bijection. Let $L' = f(L)$. We know that we can decide $L'$ and we can build a TM which can perform the function $f$. Thus we can decide $L$ using a TM which first does the mapping $f$ and then uses the TM for language $L'$. Therefore we can decide all languages over $\{ 0, 1\}$. This is a contradiction.